# MacBook Air, Mavericks and two USB-DisplayLink-Adapters and position of monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a MBA 2013 with a Thunderbold-Display (middle) and two USB 3.0 Display-Adapters (left and right).

After the upgrade to Mavericks, I have to adjust the positioning of the monitors after every restart.

This means: After a restart the Thunderbold-Display is set to be the left monitor, while the other two monitors are set to be the middle and right one.

Any suggestions? This setup worked with 10.8

Comment: Checked your permissions in Disk Utility? Sounds like your preferences are not saved, this might be due to insufficient rights. Else try to login as another user (not Guest), set your displays, reboot and login as that other user.

Comment: It does not work! I tried both suggestions and there is no way to get it run.

I tried it with just one Display-Link-Adapter (USB) and there it seems to work. 
Is there any problem in handling two similar USB-Devices?

Comment: I have no experience with USB devices. Are they connected to a USB splitter or directly to your machine. Can't help you any further. sorry.

Comment: They are connect through an ANKER USB 3.0 Hub with 7 Ports. I will try to connect the adapters directly. I also found a blog post about resetting the SMC...

Comment: I think your USB hub is the issue. Each screen has a 'DisplayID', this ID makes it possible for OS X to determin of you have your work screen attached or your home screen. The screen ID is unique per screen. Because you use USB devices as a screen, it might be that it can not capture the correct screen ID. Just a wild guess. I prefer `cscreen` to check for this (http://www.pyehouse.com/cscreen/). You can also use it to setup your display positions in a script...

Comment: ... but your setup worked in 10.8, so my previous post wont matter.

Comment: Ok. Despite this, I will try it.

Comment: Hello again,
I checked the screen ID with the tool you mentioned - they are different and seems to be unique. I didn't find any option to set the display position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue. DisplayLink and Apple are working on it...

Source: http://www.displaylink.com/support/ticket.php?id=354

Answer (score 0):

The USB-Hub is not the Problem. If you only use one Displaylink Adapter, it works fine.
I have the same on MachBook Pro Late 2008 and 2 Adapters.

Comment: But why did it work with Mac OSX 10.8?